# React Native IAP ios

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

I have a doubt about **IAP**,can we make the prices dynamic, I have an app that sells digital contents and the apple rejected the app,
since I was using a third party payment and instructed me to buy using inapp purchases but since my products price is dynamic and products can be added in future also and cart is also included, I have no idea how to implement that with in-app purchases.can you kindly guide me here..thanks in advance

Comment: IAP prices are fixed and set on App Store connect to prevent hacking fraud. You can provide a system for people to purchase "credits" using IAP and then redeem these for the products

Comment: Thanks for the information.can we use wallet kind of payment where the customer purchases credits using IAP and then use that for purchasing the goods, will that kind of scenario be rejected by apple store?

Comment: That is the same sort of thing I was describing. Only Apple will say what they will approve, but I think it would be acceptable.